# Formula to put 1 in the first value and 0 for the rest. Duplicate dataset

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, pivot-table

I'm looking for a smart way to indicate only one row with duplicated values. I need it to help my pivot table a little.

```
Id Description Estimation(h) Formula
1  Desc1       20            1
1  Desc2       20            0
1  Desc3       20            0
2  Desc4       30            1
2  Desc5       30            0
2  Desc6       30            0
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks quite simple: I just put the value `1` as the first value, and the rest of the column is based on the following formula:

```
=IF(A2=A3;0;1)
```

(I've put this formula in cell `D3`)

Answer (score 1):

This option will work even if the `Id` is not sorted:

```
=--(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1)
```

[image]